# Yii2 How to split layout file to separate header and footer?

Tags: php, yii2

I am new to `YII2`, so this can be very basic question.

I have set up initial application. I have setup theme for my `YII2` application `/themes/standard`

Now, There is a default layout file `themes/standard/layouts/main.php` - This has the html code for header and footer

I want to separate the header code into `themes/standard/layouts/header.php` and footer into another file

I tried something like below code in `main.php`

```
<?php $this->render("header"); ?>
```

tried this as well

```
<?php $this->render("//layouts/header"); ?>
```

But It doesn't render the content.
I don't want to absolute path since I have theming
Can you people help with this one?

Comment: I tried both the below statements <? $this->render("//layouts/header"); ?> and <? $this->render("header"); ?>

Comment: first of all, if you want those pages in layouts you cannot use the render function as render() belongs to a controller and layouts does not have such thing. But site does. So either you change your page logic, or you simple use `include_once()` or `require_once()` to solve this issue :)

Comment: Thanks Ares for your comments. Yeah. I just realized render belongs to Controller.

Comment: np man! glad to assist :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to have `Nested Layouts`, You can use `beginContent()` and `endContent()` like below(In your `main.php` layout for example):

```
<?php $this->beginContent('@app/views/layouts/header.php'); ?>
    <!-- You may need to put some content here -->
<?php $this->endContent(); ?>
```

Everything between `begin` and `end` will be replaced wit `$content` in `header.php`.

---

As of `Yii2`'s official example:

> Sometimes you may want to nest one layout in another. For example, in different sections of a Web site, you want to use different layouts, while all these layouts share the same basic layout that generates the overall `HTML5` page structure. You can achieve this goal by calling `beginContent()` and `endContent()` in the child layouts like the following:

```
<?php $this->beginContent('@app/views/layouts/base.php'); ?>

...child layout content here...

<?php $this->endContent(); ?>
```

> As shown above, the child layout content should be enclosed within `beginContent()` and `endContent()`. The parameter passed to `beginContent()` specifies what is the parent layout. It can be either a layout file or alias.
>   Using the above approach, you can nest layouts in more than one levels.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#nested-layouts

Comment: Done. Thanks. By the way, I may come up with more basic questions on Yii2 :) so thanks in advance..

Comment: and one more question: what is that $content in header.php? because i have just added some hardcode content in header.php and it was rendered, but not sure about that $content thing

Comment: You can put `<?php echo $content; ?>` in your `header.php` file. So everything you write between `beginContent()` and `endContent()` will be replaced with `$content` in `header.php`